# Xcode 13 on Catalina

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina, xcode13

I downloaded Xcode 13.2.1 from [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com/) but as it is not supported for macOS Catalina I cannot install it.

Are there any ways around this, other than to force upgrade to Big Sur (since it is a pain)?

[image: screenshot of my error and OS]

Comment: as of today, I cannot archive my app on Xcode 12.4 due to `Invalid bitcode version`

Comment: I did not manage to install Xcode 13 on Catalina, but I upgraded to Big Sur using https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/ on my mac mini late 2012

Comment: That's great, I'm still suffering with Catalina trying to find a way to make Xcode 12.4 support iOS 15.5

Comment: Is there any work around solution for Catalina?

Comment: @Yohanim I believe the only solution still is "OpenCore Legacy Patcher" other than changing hardware.